# Get symbols that have had their price increase within the past 6 month by 5 percent

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, average

I have the following two tables which track stock prices daily

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."security" (
    "symbol" text NOT NULL,
    "security" text NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT "security_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("symbol")
)
```

and the following table which keeps track of the security prices daily

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."security_data" (
    "ticker" text NOT NULL,
    "time" date NOT NULL,
    "low" numeric NOT NULL,
    "high" numeric NOT NULL,
    "open" numeric NOT NULL,
    "close" numeric NOT NULL,
    "volume" double precision,
    CONSTRAINT "security_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ticker", "time"),
    CONSTRAINT "security_data_ticker_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (ticker) REFERENCES security(symbol) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE
)
```

I want to come up with a SQL query that returns a list of "symbol" for stocks that had their average price for the past week higher by more than 5% than the average price for the past 6 months. I can't figure out the best way to write this query. Is it possible to write this in one query? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation. Assuming that you column `close` represents the price, you can do:

```
select ticker
from security_date
where time > current_date - '6 month'::interval
group by ticker
having avg(close) filter(where time > current_date - '1 week'::interval) 
    > 1.05 * avg(close)
```

It doesn't look like you need the "live" table to get the result you want.

Comment: Neato use of `filter`. I was thinking about joining two aggregate queries (one for the 6 months period and one for the 1 week period), but this is much more elegant. Unfortunately I'm out of votes for today, or else I would have upvoted.